# Android in app billing v3 error

Tags: android, testing, in-app

I implement in app billing v3 and its work fine for android test product_id. But when i create my own product_id in my developer account. Than upload my sigend apk as a draft and install signed apk on device and try to run the app, but I continually  get "Error while retrieving information from the server. [RPC:S-7:AEC-0]". This problem remains same even after 2 days.
Can anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, Even i faced the same previously

First method
Following the steps below.

RPC:AEC:0 error is known as CPU/RAM/Device/Identity failure.

Only possible way you can follow to get rid off this error is,

Go to settings >application > Play Store >Clear Data & Clear Cache.

Go to accounts >Google >Remove account.

Reboot device.

Again Settings>Account >Google >Log In.

if it fails,

On a computer (not tablet or phone) sign into your Google Wallet, click Payment Methods then edit to edit info.